# Looping panda's dataframe sometimes give different result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sometimes when I loop a panda's dataframe the variable in the foorloop refers to the column names of the dataframe, and other times it refers to the rows. Does anyone else have this problem?

```
for i, record in enumerate(records):
     print(record)
```

prints the colums, while other for some other dataframe (usually a langer dataframe) it prints the records,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L1787-L1796) .

`pd.DataFrame.__iter__`: it iterates along the info axis, which is the  column names.

hence, if you wish to loop through a dataframe, you should use methods such as `pd.DataFrame.iterrows()` or `pd.DataFrame.itertuples()` instead, like the followed:

```
for index, record in records.itertuples():
    print(index, record[col1], record[col2])
```